# Stance for left handed, right footed boxer?

Tags: boxing

I’ve recently started boxing and I’m left hand dominant,right leg dominant and right eye dominant. I feel more comfortable in orthodox but on the pads my coach says my left is stronger. My left would be faster but only very slightly. If I was to draw a bow and arrow I would pull it back with my right. So do I stay orthodox, or move to southpaw?

Comment: Southpaw is for left handed boxing, but what does your coach say about this?

Comment: He told me to box in whatever stance is most comfortable

Answer (score 1):

This is a personal choice at the end of the day.

Biomechanically a southpaw boxer has the advantage against an orthodox boxer in liver placement and in the fact that their power hand is aligned to it.

The majority of boxers are orthodox so being a southpaw you will see a lot of orthodox boxers while they will not see a lot of southpaws, you will also have the advantage there.

But it all boils down to where you're best at. Pick one and master it, if you get skilled enough you'll be able to switch stances in the middle of a bout.